# Linguistics: perfect and imperfect aspects of a verb considered to be the same "word" (lemma)?

Tags: лингвистика

Some linguists (see this [BBC article](https://www.bbc.com/news/world-44569277)) have estimated that the average native speaker has approximately 20,000 words in their vocabulary (obviously not counting all inflections and declension for cases). Likewise the Russian [ministry of education](http://en.russia.edu.ru/russian/levels/) defines C2-level (native-proficiency) as having a vocabulary of about 20,000 words.

My question is, how are verbs counted? Is `делать-сделать` counted as two words, or one word? This is a question about the definition of "[lemma](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Category:Russian_lemmas)" in Russian linguistics - do Russian linguists consider two aspects of the same verb to be from the same lemma, the same word?

I would appreciate any references to academic studies in Russian on the subject of counting the number of words in the language.

Answer (score 5):

The Grammatical Dictionary of Russian (which the Ministry of Education and Science [recommends](https://rg.ru/2009/08/21/russkiy-slovari-dok.html) as a normative reference) treats different aspect verbs as different lemmas:

> Члены видовой пары глаголов рассматриваются как самостоятельные слова (каждое со своей парадигмой).

http://gramdict.ru/preface1#aspect